# Combine dictionary and list

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of employeeids and the corresponding employee name below:

```
{
    '0': 'Hiro',
    '1': 'Dunn',
    '2': 'Sue',
    '3': 'Chi',
    '4': 'Thor',
    '5': 'Clive',
    '6': 'Hicks',
    '7': 'Devin',
    '8': 'Kate',
    '9': 'Klein',
}
```

I also have a list here that shows the "friends" of the employees. The two columns represent the employee ids of the respective employees.

```
[
    ['0', '1'],
    ['0', '2'],
    ['1', '2'],
    ['1', '3'],
    ['2', '3'],
    ['3', '4'],
    ['4', '5'],
    ['5', '6'],
    ['5', '7'],
    ['6', '8'],
    ['7', '8'],
    ['8', '9'],
]
```

I need these two to be appended in a way that would result the id of the employee, their name, and then the ids of their "Friends" to the right. I have literally no idea how to begin doing this. I’m stressing out more than I have in a while. Does anyone have any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of one of the result entries you are looking for, and what type it is?

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
employee_names = {
    '0': 'Hiro',
    '1': 'Dunn',
    '2': 'Sue',
    '3': 'Chi',
    '4': 'Thor',
    '5': 'Clive',
    '6': 'Hicks',
    '7': 'Devin',
    '8': 'Kate',
    '9': 'Klein',
}

friend_edges = [
    ['0', '1'],
    ['0', '2'],
    ['1', '2'],
    ['1', '3'],
    ['2', '3'],
    ['3', '4'],
    ['4', '5'],
    ['5', '6'],
    ['5', '7'],
    ['6', '8'],
    ['7', '8'],
    ['8', '9'],
]

friends_graph = {employee_id: [] for employee_id in employee_names}
for u, v in friend_edges:
    friends_graph[u].append(v)
    friends_graph[v].append(u)

print(friends_graph)
```

might help you.
It results in 
`{'0': ['1', '2'], '1': ['0', '2', '3'], '2': ['0', '1', '3'], '3': ['1', '2', '4'], '4': ['3', '5'], '5': ['4', '6', '7'], '6': ['5', '8'], '7': ['5', '8'], '8': ['6', '7', '9'], '9': ['8']}`

Not sure if you need the employee name in the resulting dict as well?  You can always use the original dict to get the employee name from any id.

Comment: This might be just what I’m looking for! Thank you !